# Execute function X amount of times between two dates, how would I do it?

Tags: python, datetime, for-loop, if-statement

If I was able to execute a function a (user-specified) amount of time between two dates, how would I do it?

Am I on the right track?

```
from datetime import date, datetime
from upload import *

current_time = datetime.utcnow()
start_time = datetime.time.hour(17)
end_time = datetime.time.hour(20)

imageposts = []
post_limit = 0

for imagepost in imageposts:
    if start_time <= current_time & current.time <= end_time & post_limit <= 3:
        try:
            upload()
            postlimit += 1
        except:
            print('Current time is not between times')
```

Comment: What are you wanting to loop in your code, is `post_limit` the amount of times you want to loop?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from upload import *

current_time = datetime.utcnow()
year, month, day = current_time.year, current_time.month, current_time.day
start_time = datetime(year, month, day, 17)
end_time = datetime(year, month, day, 20, 59, 59)

imageposts = []
post_limit = 0

for imagepost in imageposts:
    if start_time <= current.time <= end_time and post_limit <= 3:
        try:
            upload()
            post_limit += 1
        except:
            print('Current time is not between times')
```

Comment: Upvote for (personally) enlightening way to use `datetime`.